# Different number of arguments in function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I've got a few sorting functions with a different ammount of arguments, ex:

`sort1(double tab[], long n        )
 sort2(double tab[], long n, long p)`.

I need to write a funtion pointer in which I can call both of those functions. I've managed doing it using two pointers (one for functions with 2 arguments and one for 3 arguments) but got told off. It needs to be one function. This is what I came up with earlier.

```
void s1(void (*fun[])(double*, long      ), double tab[], long n)
void s2(void (*fun[])(double*, long, long), double tab[], long n)
```

And these are the arrays with function names:

```
void (*funs1[])(double tab[],         long n) = {bs, is, ss, hs};
void (*funs2[])(double tab[], long p, long n) = {qs, ms};
```

Comment: Typically in C you'll write one function that takes the maximum number of arguments and then checks the arguments for guard values. In other words, if -1 or 0 is an invalid value for that parameter, you can pass in that invalid value to tell the function that you don't want to use it. In the function, check for guard values and execute the appropriate sort.

Comment: So you suggest adding an additional argument for `sort1`, and not use it at all?

Comment: You could do it that way, or just have `sort2` check the value of the second argument. If it's an invalid value, just perform the operation that `sort1` performed.

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question?

Comment: It's C++, as stated in the tag

Comment: Then you should provide more information on requirements, cause in C++ it is done different way either by `std::function` and/or template sort function

Comment: What other information should I give? I need all of the functions to be called by one function pointer

Comment: You might achieve this with a variadic function pointer, such as void (*fun[])(double tab[], ...); However I would suggest perhaps looking at a functor, or a template solution if compile-time resolution is acceptable.

Comment: The problem is that it's an assignment for algorithimcs classes and we're forced to use function pointers

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking I believe a function pointer can store any other function pointer, as long as it is cast back to its original form before being evaluated. So a function pointer could be:

```
typedef void (*funp)();
funp f = (funp)funs2;
f = (funp)funs1;

((void (*)(double *,long))f)(NULL, 1);
```

That being said, consider a functor or template solution, as it will likely yield better results.